# Selecting the latest two distinct records from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that consists of multiple records for type INT (CUSTOMER) and need to get the last two distinct transactions for the NAME of the account. So, in my SQL, I have the following which provides the latest 4 transactions which are all correct (I have to select the latest 4 records, because, as you see selecting the latest two would result in both records being NAME 'JOHNSON'):

```
SQL> SELECT ID, NAME, DATE, CUSTOMER
    FROM (select * from ORDER_TABLE ORDER BY DATE DESC) ORDER_TABLE
    WHERE rownum <= 4
    and (CUSTOMER = 1002) 
    ORDER BY rownum DESC;

        ID NAME                DATE         CUSTOMER
---------- ------------------- ---------    ----------
        90 SMITH               26-DEC-17    1002
       135 JOHNSON             09-DEC-17    1002
       235 JOHNSON             01-JAN-18    1002
       322 JOHNSON             04-JAN-18    1002
```

However, what I need returned are only the latest DISTINCT NAME orders, so rather than the output above, I would like to see only:

```
        90 SMITH               26-DEC-17    1002
       322 JOHNSON             04-JAN-18    1002
```

Is there a query that I could perform in a single statement to get the required output? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: What is your Oracle version? Different solutions are available in different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way - using analytic functions. It is a bit complicated; unfortunately, `count(distinct ...)` can be used as analytic function, but only with a `partition by` clause - not with an `order by` clause as well. So we have to manually create that ourselves, using the start-of-group technique.

Note that the first subquery in the WITH clause is there only to generate the test data; if you use this against an actual table, remove it from the code and make sure the table name in the second subquery (and the column names!) is/are correct. I replaced the column name `date` with `dt`; `date` is a reserved word and should not be used as a column name.

I am showing a general solution - you can certainly filter for a single customer number, if needed. (Or, if you always need this with a single customer at a time, you can simplify the query somewhat.)

```
with
  tbl ( id, name, dt, customer ) as (
    select  90, 'SMITH'  , to_date('26-DEC-17', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1002 from dual union all
    select 135, 'JOHNSON', to_date('09-DEC-17', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1002 from dual union all
    select 235, 'JOHNSON', to_date('01-JAN-18', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1002 from dual union all
    select 322, 'JOHNSON', to_date('04-JAN-18', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1002 from dual
  ),
  flg ( id, name, dt, customer, flag ) as (
    select id, name, dt, customer,
           case when lag(name) over (partition by customer order by dt desc) = name
                then null else 1 end
    from   tbl
  ),
  prep ( id, name, dt, customer, sm ) as (
    select id, name, dt, customer,
           sum(flag) over (partition by customer order by dt desc)
    from   flg
  )
select max(id) keep (dense_rank first order by dt desc) as id,
       name, max(dt) as dt, customer
from   prep
where  sm <= 2
group by customer, name
;

        ID NAME    DT          CUSTOMER
---------- ------- --------- ----------
        90 SMITH   26-DEC-17       1002
       322 JOHNSON 04-JAN-18       1002
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, `match_recognize` does quick work of such requirements (and is usually quite a bit faster than analytic function approaches).

I will not write a whole tutorial on `match_recognize` in this Answer; let me just point out that `{-  ...  -}` in the `PATTERN` syntax means those rows are part of the match definition, but those rows are excluded from the output. The rest is an elementary application of `match_recognize`.

I am showing a general solution - you can certainly filter for a single customer number, if needed. (Or, if you always need this with a single customer at a time, you can simplify the query somewhat.)

```
with
  tbl ( id, name, dt, customer ) as (
    select  90, 'SMITH'  , to_date('26-DEC-17', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1002 from dual union all
    select 135, 'JOHNSON', to_date('09-DEC-17', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1002 from dual union all
    select 235, 'JOHNSON', to_date('01-JAN-18', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1002 from dual union all
    select 322, 'JOHNSON', to_date('04-JAN-18', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1002 from dual
  )
select *
from   tbl
match_recognize(
  partition by customer
  order by dt desc
  all rows per match
  pattern ( ^ a {- b* -} c )
  define b as name = a.name
);

  CUSTOMER DT                ID NAME  
---------- --------- ---------- -------
      1002 04-JAN-18        322 JOHNSON
      1002 26-DEC-17         90 SMITH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, date, customer
FROM   order_table
WHERE  (name, date) IN 
       (SELECT name, max(date)
        FROM   order_table
        WHERE  customer = 1002
        GROUP BY name)
;
```

Of course using IN is not the best in huge tables, and you can use a inner join.

Comment: It seems you didn't understand the question. Where in the query do you select rows with the two most recent DISTINCT NAMES for the same customer? See the OP's required output. Also, you can test your query using the test data from my answers.

Comment: Thanks for the negative marking. I created a table, inserted the data, tested the query before posting the answer and it worked.

Comment: Now add one more row to the table you created, with a third different name for the same customer, and see what your query produces.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE SANORD ( ID INT, NAME VARCHAR2(20), ODATE DATE, CUST INT);
Table created.

INSERT INTO SANORD VALUES (90, 'SMITH','26-DEC-17',1002);
1 row created.

INSERT INTO SANORD VALUES (135, 'JOHNSON','09-DEC-17',1002);
1 row created.

INSERT INTO SANORD VALUES (235, 'JOHNSON','01-JAN-18',1002);
1 row created.

INSERT INTO SANORD VALUES (322, 'JOHNSON','04-JAN-18',1002);
1 row created.

COMMIT;

SELECT id, name, odate, cust
FROM   sanord
WHERE  (name, odate) IN
       ( select name, max(odate) from sanord where cust = 1002 group by name)
;

        ID NAME                 ODATE           CUST
---------- -------------------- --------- ----------
        90 SMITH                26-DEC-17       1002
       322 JOHNSON              04-JAN-18       1002
```

Comment: Now add one more row to the table you created, with a third different name for the same customer, and see what your query produces.

Comment: You could come across a little more friendly, a little less passive aggressive :) This is my first post and a negative marking was a fantastic welcome, thanks. I am not an expert like you. If only experts answered questions, this place would be a little lonely!  I inserted another row with the name MARK and got three rows. I can see where you are heading with your argument, but the OP's request can be interpreted differently. 2 confusing requests  "need to get the last two distinct transactions for the NAME of the account." and "what I need returned are only the latest DISTINCT NAME orders,"

Comment: Sorry if you felt offended; I upvote and downvote answers based strictly on whether I believe they are helpful or not, with no regard to who the poster is or to their reputation. I have upvoted answers from beginners and downvoted answers from experts in the past (sometimes incorrectly - it happens); this is how the site is supposed to work. Don't feel discouraged by my downvote, it is not a personal opinion on you - it's only on one isolated answer.